Insulating an attached garage in wisconsin
Insulating an attached Garage in Wisconsin
Hi all! My wife and I recently bought our first house (5 years old) in southern Wisconsin this summer. We wanted to insulate our attached garage, but are at a loss. Especially for the attic above the garage. I assume for the walls of the garage I would do R13 insulation rolls with the vapor barrier on the inside. Then we were going to put OBX board over the front. However for the attic I’ve been seeing a lot of differences.
We would probably install a small heater into the garage as well as I also do a bit of woodworking. Your help to confirm my thoughts on the walls, and help with how much to put in the attic is appreciated!

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Maybe this answer is useful: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/223952/77514

If the walls are not atypical, go with filling the stud cavities, then sheeting over with solid insulation, then plywood/drywall (usually plywood/OSB where you want to attach stuff to the walls and drywall elsewhere.) Limiting yourself to what you can stuff in the cavities is "cheap fuel era" mentality (or "not very cold area" mentality) and rather outdated these days.

If they are 2X4 walls, R-13 is cool, There is a chance you have 2X6 outside walls you could go with R-19 or R-21.
For your attic, you will want to go with what can afford. It may get pricy, getting what you could use in Wisconsin. If you went by code, and I did't check before I wrote this, but you may need to go more than R-48.
If I were doing it, and if you are serious abot keeping what heat you put into it, or for that matter cooler in the summer (I am in WA state and our garage is really hot in the summertime) I would get R-13, maybe R-19 stapled up really well. If you have drywall on the ceiling already, you can skip this step. After that is in, rent a blowing wool machine and get in as much as you can afford. This wool will fall in the spaces that would otherwise be left open, unless you did a lot of careful cutting and stuffing. If you have drywall already, fill'er up. don't sweat the R-13 or R-19.
One thing you may need to do first before you add any insulation in the attic, in any fashion. Install baffles at the outside walls so the insulation going in, does not block the passageway for venting the hot air from the now closed in space. Presumably, you have a ridge vent or other venting to make the venting package complete.

Thank you! There is drywall on the ceiling already. So by fill it up do I fill it past the ceiling joists? Very new to home ownership!

R-48 will be about 14" to 16" of depth. I hope the builder had the foresight to place baffles in between the trusses before the sheetrock was set. The rental places can tell you how much it will take. Give them the attic area (IE: 20'X20', or 24'X 26') and they can figure it from there. Then that will tell you how much it will cost. Between the rental and the cost per bag, the rental place may need to tell you how much to put in, in case the budget is tight. You will not want to start shooting it in at 16" deep, when you only have enough in the budget to cover 10" deep over the whole attic.

Also if you do not need every square inch of floor space, adding 2x2s or more to 2x4 walls will increase insulation R value you can add.
